# Terraform azure_rm multi-region best practice

Tags: terraform, azure-rm

I'm using Terraform to deploy Azure resources and now want to deploy across multiple regions.

I'm finding even with Modules I'm repeating code, once for each region.

How should I be writing code for multi region? I can't find any best practices

Comment: Could you please update this question with more detail? What specific resources are you talking about? It really matters, because how regions are handled depends on what you want to accomplish. I will attempt to give you direction via an answer, but it may not be as helpful as you need without more context from you. Be very specific, and provide code samples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really depends on your resources. Some resources are reasonably maintained as multi-region within a single module, but this is rare. This would be a case where a module specifically addresses resources in multiple regions, with some kind of unifying logic for those resources. Since regions are typically very independent by design, this is *typically* an anti-pattern.

Often, it is more sane to use an infrastructure module (or root module, which means the same thing) per region. Some methodologies would have you use a different directory for each region, and again per environment. Yes, you're repeating yourself, but not that much. Your root modules should usually be pretty small and opinionated, serving as a hub for modules and top-level resources to be called.

Yes, you should keep your code DRY, but don't get carried away with it. Some duplication for the sake of organizing resources is totally acceptable.

In the cases where this is truly a problem (large root modules, and/or many regions across many environments), there are tools that can handle this effectively for you. Terragrunt is a fairly effective one, and can template your root modules (including their backend configuration) via a single code location, which is then callable via fairly small files. This can help to deduplicate a codebase like the one I just described.

You may also design your infrastructure modules to be re-usable by defining variables for regional and environmental variances between deployments. Backend configuration is also configurable during Terraform runtime via CLI or environment variable settings. Between these two, you can create infrastructure modules that are capable of being applied in arbitrary environments and regions. I like this better than Terragrunt's approach, because it's much simpler.

How you call these re-usable modules is up to your orchestration implementation, be that a CI/CD system, Kubernetes, Terraform Enterprise/Cloud, whatever.

Hopefully that helps you to make a decision.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a list variable and put your regions inside.
Then you could create a for loop and create the resource for each region. This approach works only when you really want to have each resource in each region.